# .Net Android.Browser files

Tags: .net, mobile, httpbrowsercapabilities, browsercaps

Can anyone tell me where I can find a list of Browser capabilities for the Android platform? I need to construct a .Browser file for it as part of my ASP.Net MVC3 project.

Some links would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Gineer

**Update:** I've looked at both 51degrees.mobi and WURFL. These seem overkill for my requirements. Additionally company policie prohibits the use of Open Source software. I know WURFL have a commercial license available, but then the costs become prohibitive for our requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use the [51 Degrees.Mobi dll's](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/51Degrees.mobi) *<-- Link to Nuget Package*

It is based on the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) database and will provide you with the best available list of browser capabilities.

Or you could just use the [WURFL .Net API directly](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotNet/).

**UPDATE:**

I wouldn't consider using WURFL overkill for your needs. There are [hundreds of different Android devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) with dozens being added every couple of months. [Google is activating 500,000+ Android devices **EVERY DAY!**](http://www.unwiredview.com/2011/07/14/google-now-activates-550k-androids-per-day-135-million-devices-sold-market-reaches-250000-apps/)

**Even if you build the browser file yourself, it will be obsolete in a few months.**

Tell your employer that it will take you less time to use the aforementioned components than it did to write this question on SO.

Comment: I've looked at both 51degrees.mobi and WURFL. These seem overkill for my requirements. Additionally company policie prohibits the use of Open Source software. I know WURFL have a commercial license available, but then the costs become prohibitive for our requirements.

Comment: @Gineer - I have worked at companies where they have such draconian policies. However, if you come back with a well prepared and reasoned argument they may bend. Here are the key points: *1.)* Microsoft is no longer providing updated browser files *2.)* WURFL is the best source of browser capabilities, and therefore you would probably need to use it to build your browser file *3.)* Keeping this up to date would incur a huge development cost and overhead *4.)* Using WURFL would eliminate that cost, and save the company money

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know if it's an Android device or not and not which specific device.  This is effective enough:

```
<browsers>
  <gateway id="Android" parentID="Safari">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="Android" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="mobileDeviceModel"               value="Android" />
      <capability name="isMobileDevice"                  value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </gateway>
</browsers>
```